# Unity frame Drop when Screen.orientaion change

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hi I have Frame drop issue when Screen.orientaion change on android

In my Project has Play video funtion with Udate(){Texture2d}

and the Button that works this code

```cs
if (CurrentScreenMode == ScreenMode.Vertical)
{
    Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
    //do ui set for portrait
}
else
{
    Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeRight;
    //do ui set for Landscape
}
```

call several times that code then video Frame is down

but if application down on background and return the application

Video frame becomes good

what is the problem??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

It is occurred by sync issue between CPU and GPU

so, I edit it CPU wait for GPU works